# What method did Julia use?

Tags: methods, julia, multiple-dispatch

I have defined the following variable

```
julia> X = (1:10) * ones(1,10)
```

which defines a matrix with each row equals to the same number and the numbers in the column increasing from 1 to 10 by 1. I want to know which method used Julia for the function `*`. How can I ask that to Julia?

Comment: That's [matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication)

Comment: I know it @Daniel, just I want that Julia tells me that I am using the method that is defined like `*(UnitRange{Int64}, Array{Float64,2})`

Comment: I'm not very good at interpreting the output, but `@code_warntype (1:10) * ones(1,10)` might tell you what you need to know. As near as I can tell (and I emphasize this is not something I know much about), ultimately `*` appears to be calling `Base.LinAlg.generic_matmatmul!` on two input `Array{Float64, 2}`. Hopefully someone a bit more knowledgeable can chip in.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`@which` is what you are looking for:

```
@which (1:10) * ones(1, 10)
# *(A::AbstractArray{T,1}, B::AbstractArray{T,2}) at linalg/matmul.jl:89
```

in [Jupyter](https://jupyter.org) it will also hyperlink to the corresponding [line of code](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/a2f713dea5ac6320d8dcf2835ac4a37ea751af05/base/linalg/matmul.jl#L89) where the method is defined in Julia's GitHub.

Comment: Interesting. Is there a way to iteratively dig deeper? ie, the line referenced in your answer calls `*` again, but on two abstract matrices. Is there a way to get `@which` to also tell us which method was called next? (presumably in this case it was `*` for two `Matrix{Float64}`?)

Comment: @colin No that I know of but I'm sure there is a metaprogramming way of doing it.

Comment: @ColinTBowers if you got that line of code, you can check the next-`*` by `which(*, (Matrix{Float64},Matrix{Float64}))` manually.

Comment: is this tracing nightmare a drawback of multiple dispatch? :p

Comment: @amrods i guess what Colin want is just the `Jump to Definition` functionality in most of modern IDEs which can be used to dig out more info about `*` iteratively in this specific case.

Comment: @GnimucK. "`which(*, (Matrix{Float64},Matrix{Float64}))`" -> yep, that does it. As amrods suggests, there's probably a neat little function that can be written here to iterate up the chain. Thanks for responding (both of you).

Comment: When tracing code this way, I assign new names to my variables that match the arguments of the function found by `@which`. Then I copy/paste lines of code from that function into the REPL until I get to the next line I want to trace, and use `@which` again. Saves you from having to be sure about the types.